# Postgresql, retrieve value for specific key from json array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have Postgres JSONB array of objects, looking like this :

```
'[
  {
    "skillId": "1",
    "skillLevel": 42
  },
  {
    "skillId": "2",
    "skillLevel": 41
  }
]'
```

This JSONB is a function argument.

What is the most efficient way to retrieve `skillLevel` for  `skillId = "1"`.

I've tried to play with `jsonb_array_elements` but everything I've done so far is looking really messy.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In **Postgres 9.4+** use the function `jsonb_array_elements()` in a lateral join:

```
select (elem->>'skillLevel')::int as skill_level
from my_table
cross join jsonb_array_elements(json_col) elem
where elem->>'skillId' = '1';
```

You can implement the idea in a simple function, e.g:

```
create or replace function extract_skill_level(json_data jsonb, id int)
returns integer language sql as $$
    select (elem->>'skillLevel')::int
    from jsonb_array_elements(json_data) elem
    where elem->>'skillId' = id::text
$$;

select extract_skill_level(json_col, 1) as skill_level
from my_table;
```

In **Postgres 12+** you have a nice alternative in the form of jsonb path functions:

```
select (
    jsonb_path_query(
        json_col, 
        '$[*] ? (@.skillId == "1")'
        )->'skillLevel'
    )::int as skill_level
from my_table;
```

[Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5af672da039ab117db36dfd7abac2899)

Read more about [JSON Functions and Operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)